# moderncv 2.0.0 not producing a pdf

Tags: errors, moderncv

I have been trying to create a CV with the documentclass moderncv, but on my computer (Ubuntu 16.04), I have been receiving the following result after using pdflatex:

```
This is is pdfTeX, Version 4.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 
2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./resume.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncv.cls
Document Class: moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and 
letter document class ...
No pages of output.
```

with the following source:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\name{John}{Doe}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

This persisted even after I uninstalled and then reinstalled LaTeX with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

Comment: that appears to be the expected output from that input (I get the same) try starting from a bigger example

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\name{John}{Doe}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

It seems you need to define the style to have an output.